# xslt apply-template

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Unable to succeed in passing parameters in xsl (1.0) for . It seems that one cannot dynamically modify the content of the 'select'. Below is an attempt that does not throw an error but fails to recognise the **$entity** parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>   
    <xsl:param name="entity">CreditController[]</xsl:param>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:element name="variable">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">NameValuePair[]</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="variable/*[@type='$entity']/item"/>                      
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">                 
            <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">NameValuePair</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="value">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">String</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="name">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">String</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>-<xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance. Other posts seemed to recommend using  and also setting 'Mode' attribute of the  element. I did not win with either of these.

Replacing the entity variable with the string literal 'CreditController[]' works as expected.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input xml?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `@type=$entity`? Surrounding the `$entity` with quotes makes it the string `$entity`.

Comment: Avila's answer is correct I think, and should have been entered as an answer so it could be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XPath you surround your `$entity` with quotes, making it the string literal `$entity` and not a variable to be expanded.

Remove the quotes:

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="variable/*[@type=$entity]/item"/>
```